# Mathematically find the value that is closest to 0

Tags: algorithm, math, micro-optimization, branch-prediction, absolute-value

Is there a way to determine mathematically if a value is closer to 0 than another?

For example `closerToZero(-2, 3)` would return `-2`.

I tried by removing the sign and then compared the values for the minimum, but I would then be assigning the sign-less version of the initial numbers.

a and b are IEEE-754 compliant floating-point doubles (js number)

(64 bit => 1 bit sign 11 bit exponent 52 bit fraction)

```
min (a,b) => b-((a-b)&((a-b)>>52));
result = min(abs(a), abs(b));
// result has the wrong sign ...
```

Comment: In python, you can do `min(a, b, key=abs)`.

Comment: Other languages might have something called `argmin` instead of `min`. And if really the language doesn't have such a function in their standard library, it's easy to code with a simple iteration over the list of values. However your question doesn't ask about a specific language. In fact, it's really unclear what your question is exactly.

Comment: Do you need to do this branchlessly?  Or are you just hoping to make it efficient for unpredictable values?  Not clear from the [tag:branch-prediction] tag, because your code has no branches to predict and you didn't say anything in the text.

Comment: In math you would write it like this: a if abs(a)<=abs(b), b otherwise. This is equally easy to translate to a programming language.

Comment: @Henry: In languages with fixed-with 2's complement integers, make sure you do an unsigned compare of the `abs` results so you correctly handle `abs(INT_MIN)` which (if done signed) would overflow back to INT_MIN even though it's maximally far from 0.  But yes, `abs(a) < (unsigned) abs(b) ? a : b` should work in languages where the return value of `abs` is stupidly signed.  Except that still involves signed overflow in C, which is undefined behaviour, if abs is actually done signed.  So you'd really want to implement your own `absu(int)` as `return x<0? 0U - x : x;`

Comment: @Henry Thanks!  Somehow I forgot that I could assign variables conditionally -.-

Comment: @PeterCordes Will write an answer with your addition to Henries comment if none of you will beat me to it

Comment: I was already turning my comment into an answer, since I realized it basically was one already.  I assume you're targeting a low-ish level language like C or C++ and caring about how they compile to asm, based on the branch-prediction tag.

Comment: You can avoid the INT_MIN problem by mapping positive numbers to negative, instead of vice versa.

Comment: @kaya3: Oh neat, that's an interesting trick for languages that don't give easy access to unsigned.  (Like Java I think?)  In C it's fully possible to avoid signed overflow in the C abstract machine, but still compile fully efficiently to asm on a 2's complement machine with `0U - x` instead of `(unsigned)-x`, i.e. converting `x` to unsigned before subtraction.  https://godbolt.org/z/K4abbf

Comment: is `a` and `b` integer or float?

Comment: What language are you using that allows bitwise binary AND with `&`, and right shifts, on doubles?

Comment: @PeterCordes that is js :D I wanted to push an entity collision system to its limits for fun by doing everything possible to optimize the code. (Am copying the collision system from frostbite). Debranching usually nets somewhere from 20 - 40% speed increase in js on V8

Comment: Oh, so you're triggering implicit conversion from FP to integer with JavaScript `&`, I think, not manipulating actual FP bit-patterns.  Ideally you can write something that lets V8 keep the values at 32-bit `int` instead of actually converting back to double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious algorithm is to *compare* the absolute values, and use that to *select* the original values.

If this absolutely needs to be branchless (e.g. for crypto security), be careful with `? :` ternary.  It often compiles to branchless asm but that's not guaranteed.  (I assume that's why you tagged [branch-prediction](/questions/tagged/branch-prediction)?  If it was just out of performance concerns, the compiler will generally make good decisions.)

**In languages with fixed-with 2's complement integers, remember that `abs(INT_MIN)` overflows a signed result of the same width as the input.**  [In C and C++, `abs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) is inconveniently designed to return an `int` and it's undefined behaviour to call it with the most-negative 2's complement integer, on 2's complement systems.  On systems with well-defined wrapping signed-int math (like `gcc -fwrapv`, or maybe Java), signed `abs(INT_MIN)` would overflow back to INT_MIN, giving wrong results if you do a signed compare because INT_MIN is maximally far from 0.

**Make sure you do an unsigned compare of the `abs` results so you correctly handle `INT_MIN`.**  (Or as @kaya3 suggests, map positive integers to negative, instead of negative to positive.)

### Safe C implementation that avoids Undefined Behaviour:

```
unsigned absu(int x) {
    return x<0? 0U - x : x;
}

int minabs(int a, int b) {
    return absu(a) < absu(b) ? a : b;
}
```

Note that `<` vs. `<=` actually matters in `minabs`: that decides which one to select if their magnitudes are equal.

`0U - x` converts `x` to `unsigned` *before* a subtract from 0 which can overflow.  Converting negative signed-integer types to unsigned is well-defined in C and C++ as modulo reduction (unlike for floats, UB IIRC).  On 2's complement machines that means using the same bit-pattern unchanged.

This compiles nicely for x86-64 ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/K4abbf)), especially with clang.  (GCC avoids `cmov` even with `-march=skylake`, ending up with a worse sequence.  Except for the final select after doing both absu operations, then it uses `cmovbe` which is 2 uops instead of 1 for `cmovb` on Intel CPUs, because it needs to read both ZF and CF flags.  If it ended up with the opposite value in EAX already, it could have used `cmovb`.)

```
# clang -O3
absu:
        mov     eax, edi
        neg     eax                # sets flags like sub-from-0 
        cmovl   eax, edi           # select on signed less-than condition
        ret

minabs:
        mov     ecx, edi
        neg     ecx
        cmovl   ecx, edi             # inlined absu(a)
        mov     eax, esi
        mov     edx, esi
        neg     edx
        cmovl   edx, esi             # inlined absu(b)
        cmp     ecx, edx             # compare absu results
        cmovb   eax, edi             # select on unsigned Below condition.
        ret
```

Fully branchless with both GCC and clang, with optimization enabled.  It's a safe bet that other ISAs will be the same.

It might auto-vectorize decently, but x86 doesn't have SIMD unsigned integer compares until AVX512.  (You can emulate by flipping the high bit to use signed integer `pcmpgtd`).

For float / double, `abs` is cheaper and can't overflow: just clear the sign bit, then use that to select the original.